# Elasticsearch terms aggregation returns no buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

New elasticsearch user here and having an issue with a terms aggregation.
I have indexed 187 documents with fields like "name","host","risk" etc.
The field risk has 4 unique values ("Critical","High","Medium","Low","Informational")
I am running a terms aggregations like this:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/{index_name}/_search?size=0

{
    "aggs":{
        "riskCount":{
            "terms":{ 
                "field":"risk.keyword"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting a result stating that i have x of Critical, x of High etc.
Thing is, i get no buckets returned.

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 187,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "riskCount": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        }
    }
}
```

My Elasticsearch version is 7.12.0 Any ideas

- Edit:
  So, here's the mapping:

  ```
  "findings": {
       "mappings": {
           "properties": {
               "date_uploaded": {
                   "type": "date"
               },
               "host": {
                   "type": "text"
               },
               "name": {
                   "type": "text"
               },
               "risk": {
                   "type": "text"
               }
           }
       }
   }
  ```

And here's the document:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 187,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "findings",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "f86b6b5b-f09e-4350-9a66-d88a3a78f640",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "risk": "Informational",
                    "name": "HTTP Server Type and Version",
                    "host": "10.10.9.10",
                    "date_uploaded": "2021-05-07T19:39:10.810663+00:00"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your index mapping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `risk` field is of `text` type, you need to [update your index mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex) as

```
PUT /_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "risk": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then run the [update_by_query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) to reindex the data

Comment: ...And also run `_update_by_query` so that the sub-fields get created ;-)

Comment: Yes, @Val :-) Thank u for pointing this out :D

Comment: Sorry for pointing this so late, but i am indexing these via a library called elasticsearch-dsl. Will running this PUT request break anything?

Comment: @MachosV this will not break anything. The update mapping API will just create multifield for the `risk` field. This will enable you to perform aggregation on the `risk` field. And update by query API will reindex the data

Comment: Oh sweet lord, it worked. Gods, it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can't upvote since this is my first time posting a question, but i did accept it as an answer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `risk.keyword` field in your mapping. You need to change your mapping as follows. Just run the following command to update your mapping and create the `risk.keyword` sub-field:

```
PUT index-name/_mapping
{
      "properties": {
        "date_uploaded": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "risk": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Then reindex your data using this command:

```
POST index-name/_update_by_query
```

And then your query can be run like this:

```
{
    "aggs":{
        "riskCount":{
            "terms":{ 
                "field":"risk.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried running the aggregation on just the risk field, but i get an error stating that Text fields are not optimized for aggregations etc.. Thanks for taking the time to answer though!

Comment: Ok, then your query is correct. Can you share your mapping and a sample document that contains a value for that field?